# How to increase sndbuf/rcvbuf size socket options in Perl Socket module?

Tags: perl, sockets

In Perl (v5.10) Socket module, by default, (for some reason) the socket options sndbuf and rcvbuf bytes have very low values of 5 bytes and 60 bytes respectively.
When I try to increase to a higher value (say 4K), it would not take.

```
use Socket;

# *** someother code  ***

# Retrieve default values
my $snd_size = unpack("I", getsockopt(SOCK, $proto, SO_SNDBUF));
print "The default sndsize = $snd_size\n";

my $rcv_size = unpack("I", getsockopt(SOCK, $proto, SO_RCVBUF));
print "The default rcvsize = $rcv_size\n";


my $required_send_buf_size = 4096;
my $required_recv_buf_size = 4096;

my $pack_send = pack("I", $required_send_buf_size);
if (!setsockopt(SOCK, $proto, SO_SNDBUF, $pack_send))
{
    print("ERROR: Unable to set the SO_SNDBUF to $required_send_buf_size\n");
    close(SOCK);
    return;
}

$snd_size = unpack("I", getsockopt(SOCK, $proto, SO_SNDBUF));
print "The modified sndsize = $snd_size\n";


my $pack_recv = pack("I", $required_recv_buf_size);
if (!setsockopt(SOCK, $proto, SO_RCVBUF, $pack_recv))
{
    print("ERROR: Unable to set the SO_RCVBUF to $required_recv_buf_size\n");
    close(SOCK);
    return;
}
```

In the above code, both the setsockopt() calls fail.

Comment: You should include `$!` in the error message as it will be set if setsockopt fails.

Comment: Where do you set `$proto`? Is it being set to `SOL_SOCKET` somewhere?

Comment: The variable name makes me think it's some other value, which would of course explain the small numbers and errors - you're looking at completely different options if that's the case.

Comment: `$proto = getprotobyname('tcp')`

Comment: Yup, that's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$proto = getprotobyname('tcp');
...
my $snd_size = unpack("I", getsockopt(SOCK, $proto, SO_SNDBUF));
```

There's your problem right there. `SO_SNDBUF` and `SO_RCVBUF` are generic socket options, not TCP-specific ones. You're getting (And attempting to set) the TCP options that correspond to those numbers (`TCP_SYNCNT` and `TCP_LINGER2` on my linux box.). No wonder it's failing.

You need to use `SOL_SOCKET` as the level argument instead for socket options starting with `SO_`.

```
my $snd_size = unpack("I", getsockopt(SOCK, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF));
```

Comment: That worked and the buf size numbers came out as expected, Thank you Shawn!. I just used the same level that was used in creating the socket . `socket(SOCK, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto)`, now, it looks like the socket() creation is also incorrect.

Comment: Looks like I need to use `$proto = getprotobyname('tcp'))[2]`

Comment: @humility That should be fine. Normally you'd use 0 to get the default protocol for the given domain and type, but in this case that happens to be tcp anyways. (Using `IO::Socket::INET` (Or in modern versions of Perl, `IO::Socket::IP`) is an easier way to create sockets, btw.)

Comment: In scalar context, `getprotobyname` should return the number.